# Fire asp.net (link button or Button) click event using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I need to fire asp.net (link button or Button) click event(server side code)  using Jquery, the buttons are in an update panel. Kindly help.

Comment: why don't you create web method with your server side code and call it from jquery post?

Comment: As Jayantha said you need to create a webmethod. I have explained below

Comment: I cannot JQuery ajax and i have tried the JQuery trigger method but it doesn't seem to work in my application. I need alternaltive to document.getElementById('lnkMyButton').click(); which will support multiple browsers

Comment: If you have code you tried and isn't working, please post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
__doPostBack("<%= lnkMyButton.UniqueID %>", "");
```

Comment: hi @Michael, this works fine! but will you please explain about the second parameter that you set to blank?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE It's the event argument, the first parameter is the event target. Normally a button is the only thing that can trigger a post, so for LinkButtons (which are just A tags), TextBoxes with AutoPostBack=true and OnTextChanged event, etc ASP.NET uses this __doPostBack method it creates to set two hidden fields (the eventTarget so ASP.NET knows what triggered the post and eventArgument data the server control may need) and then calls document.forms["form1"].submit() to trigger the post. I've never seen LinkButton control use the eventArgument but other server controls may use it.

Answer (score 4):

Michael's solution is good.
But I think it is safer to call [GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx).
The internal structure of ASP.NET Page may be changed in the future.

Here's the sample Code.

```
  <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lnkButton, "") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to define your server side code as [WebMethod] once you do that your classname will be available to client side code for calling.

Then you would go about calling that method using something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   data: '{}',
   dataType: 'json',
   url: 'MyPage.aspx/SomePageMethod',
   success: function(result){
       alert(result);
   }
});
```

I am more of a C# person, but I would imagine if you read this page you are easily able to make it in VB: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I triggered a click event with a LinkButton within an Update Panel.  I couldn't get the ID until run time due to the way I was creating buttons, that is, it kept appending a _0, _1, etc to the end of the button name. For example on the server I would create 2 buttons with ID's say of 111555 & 222666.  It would rename the buttons with ID's like:
contentMain_gridviewMessages_111555_0
contentMain_gridviewMessages_222666_1

So the first thing I did was create a unique attribute I could search upon, in my case the message id:

```
var msgLink = ('a[messageId="' + messageId + '"]');
```

After that I used a little bit of jQuery to get the auto generated ID:

```
var id = $(msgLink).attr("ID");
```

When I got the ID good ole fashion javascript did the rest:

```
document.getElementById(id).click();
```

Hope this helps someone out.