# Why is Jquery Click not firing the ASP.NET Link Button Click event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've a Link button on a web page which is a child page of a master page. Here is the link button code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_submit"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" 
CssClass="btn btn-green submit-button pull-right btn-block">
<span class="start-text" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;">Start</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

The way I tried to do was

```
$('#lb_submit').click();
```

But its not firing the actual click event of that link button.

Also I tried

```
$('#lb_submit').trigger('click');
```

That also didnt help me to solve that issue. Actually my purpose was to trigger that button when ever the enter key on anywhere of the page. That event is working fine and I confirmed it. But am sharing that function also

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                // Cancel the default action on keypress event
                e.preventDefault();

                $('#lb_submit').click();
            }
        });
```

Im not getting an idea what I did wrong

```
<div class="col-md-2 "><a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions
(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cp_body$lb_submit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" 
class="btn btn-green submit-button pull-right btn-block" id="lb_submit">
<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;" class="start-text">Start</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the client-side markup for the link look like?  When you debug this in the browser, does `$('#lb_submit')` find the element?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: i think you can handle this click event on the server side too. Generate  a function on your code behind and write the logic there rather stressing over jQuery .

Comment: Has the document finished loading before click is called

Comment: @David Ofcourse its the same lb_submit in client side too. Hope you saw my markup of the linkbutton in which I mentioned ClientIDmode as static

Comment: @Ninsly Am using a CDN jquery from google(Most recent version)

Comment: @mjroodt Actually I think you skipped part of my question. Its happening in a event to handle Enter key on the page. So yea, Enter key presses only after the page loads completely.

Comment: @sforsandeep: There's a difference between *assuming* the client-side code is what you expect it to be and *examining* the client-side code to *confirm* that assumption.  I understand what `ClientIDMode` does.  But if you're going to be diagnosing problems with client-side functionality, a really useful first step is to look at the client-side code.  Debugging is a lot more productive than assuming.

Comment: @David Actually I confirmed that from the clientside code itself. With that reason I added ClientIDMode as static. Its not an assumption at all.

Comment: I dont know the downvoter. But requesting you for specifying the reason of downvoting.

Comment: @sforsandeep: That's a good step toward debugging, but can you share some of that debugging information in the question?  Perhaps specify exactly where/how the code is behaving differently from what is expected?  Currently this exchange is very close to saying, "Trust me, I confirmed that my code is fine so you don't need to see it.  But can you tell me why it doesn't work?"  Which is inherently unanswerable.  I'm not trying to sound rude, and I hope it's not coming across that way in this text-only medium.  It just seems that some more debugging information is required to solve the issue.

Comment: @David Dear Friend, I added the client side code.. Would you please check that.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187130/fire-asp-net-link-button-or-button-click-event-using-jquery?rq=1

Comment: How are you handling the client side click? I've tried an example here and seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/vsr3qb9b/

Comment: @mjroodt Thats right friend. I tried the same way. I wrote a JQuery click event for that linkbutton. But that Jquery click event itself is firing nicely. There my problem is. Even its JQUery event working why it doesnt invoke the server side event and also why its not validates the page which the button normally does when we click on the button manually. Its not doing any validations and no hint of the event is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#lb_submit").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually the enter key part is working perfect. The code which is not working is triggering the submit button click event. I tried an alert before that click trigger which worked fine.. So its not with the fault of Enter key handler

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the actual ID of the control as rendered by the web server is different, something like `ctl00_lb_submit`. Try this:

```
$('<%= this.lb_submit.ClientID %>').click();
```

Comment: No it wont be since I specified ClientIDmode as static. So even in client side the ID will be same as server side